# c# Added Form to Project: Possible to make it internal/private from designer?

Tags: c#, forms, access-modifiers

I have added a form to a project to create a custom message box. This message box will only be applicable from within the project so I was wondering if there was a way I could make it internal/private from the forms designer? Or do I have to change it in the code directly? Is there a reason I shouldn't do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the designer.  Just change `public` to `internal` in the code-behind class.

---

It is impossible to make a `private` top-level class.
`private` means only visible within its class; a top-level class isn't in a class.